# Regex: Delete everything from 2 tags

Tags: regex, window, notepad++

I have this kind of script. I want to select/delete all script from `<script type='text/javascript'>` to `</script>`

```
<script type='text/javascript'> window['__wavt'] = 'AOuZoY7C5YW0NbvyHBM2AbUwwOO7gpMxsA:1495265533940';_WidgetManager._Init('//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID\x3d1126651761205083490','11-povesti-in-11-minute-la-11even.html'/*tpa=http://www.sena.com/2012/05/11-povesti-in-11-minute-la-11even.html*/,'1126651761205083490');
_WidgetManager._SetDataContext([{'name': 'blog', 'data': {'blogId': '1126651761205083490', 'title': 'Richie`s Day', 'url': 'my-link.html'/*tpa=http://www.sena.com/2012/05/mylink.html*/, 'canonicalUrl': </script>
```

Anyway, I made 2 regex, but none work:

`(<script type='text/javascript'>)[\s\S]*?(</script>[\s\S]*?`

`(?-s)^.*(<script type='text/javascript'>)(?s).*?(?-s)(</script>).*(\r\n|\z)`

Answer (score 0):

sure, I find the answer:

`(?s)(<script type='text/javascript).*?(?-s)(</script>)`

or

`^.*(?s)(<script type='text/javascript).*?(?-s)(</script>).*$`

so, for anyone,

`(?s)(SELECT_FROM-PART-ONE).*?(?-s)(TO-PART-TWO)`

or

`^.*(?s)(SELECT_FROM PART-ONE).*?(?-s)(TO_PART_TWO).*$`